# How to initializing and printing individual elements an array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] anArray=new int[100];
        int i=0;


        for(i=0;i<anArray.length;i++)
        {
            anArray[i]=(i+1);
            System.out.println(anArray);
        }
}
```

This is what I have, but all I get is  printed 100 times.

> [I@58e5ebd

How to I get it to print 1-100 all on a seperate line?

Comment: You can't println the entire array, you need to print one value at a time

Comment: you're printing the entire array did you just want to print the element?

Comment: You added all of the values correctly, you did not print the array correctly.

Comment: Why do you need the array anyway?

Comment: Not a bad question.  It isn't obvious that the code would behave that way.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using the `System.out.println(anArray);`  this prints the array object itself which is `[I@58e5ebd` in your case but you need to print each of the element and you can access the element located at `index` by using `anArray[index]`

So you should use this,

```
 System.out.println(anArray[i]);
```

Comment: Looks like beginner, please explain.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish the same task without using an array (unless you're just trying to practice arrays).

```
    for( i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

**Edit: using array**. You were trying to print the array object itself. That will give you the memory location. You actually want to print the indices i.e. `anArray[0]`, index 0

```
   int[] anArray = new int[100];
   int i;

   for( i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++)
    {
        anArray[i] = (i + 1);
        System.out.println([i]);
    }
```

Note: Put spaces between operators. Makes code more readable

Comment: I would have done it that way but for this assignment I need to know how to use an array

Answer (score 1):

What you really get like the output is address of object `anArray`.
If you want to print each element of this array you have to iterate through it and print `anArray[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Code `System.out.println(anArray);` is tryin to print entire int[] array directly. Since int[]  is an reference type and it does not override `toString()` method, so you are facing `[I@58e5ebd` when you are trying to print the `int[]` array.

See, you assign each element in int[] array using  `anArray[i]=(i+1);`, you can print it directly.

So just use

```
System.out.println(anArray[i]);
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(anArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to I get it to print 1-100 all on a seperate line?

```
System.out.println(-99);
```

Comment: har har, except that would print -99, joke's on you.

Comment: Well, @turbo, this is just a case of "What you ask is what you get."

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.out.println(anArray);
```

prints object not element

correct is

```
 System.out.println(anArray[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are not printing the array's current index value but the whole array object.

```
[I@58e5ebd
```

The result as you see is not what you expected as output because that value value after the '@' is the object's hashcode in hexadecimal.

The right code to print the array's current index value is:

```
System.out.println(anArray[i]);
```